# Passing a guid by actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, actionlink

I have an  (nothing fancy) for editing a different model by a Guid.
I made a ActionResult "Edit" with a param (Guid Bedrnr), Still another Edit (int id) is available.
When I call this ActionResult I get an error message about

ambiguous between the following action methods:
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(Int32) on type DaisyMatchMaker.Controllers.BedrijfsGegevensController
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(System.Guid) on type DaisyMatchMaker.Controllers.BedrijfsGegevensController

```
 @Html.ActionLink(@item.Bedrijfsnaam.ToString(), "Edit", "BedrijfsGegevens", null, new { bedrijfsnummer = (Guid)item.Bedrijfsnummer })
```

Why??
And what is the proper ActionLink??

Cheers
Hans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is simply that you have two Actions with the same name and same parameter count. Try changing the name of one of your Action methods and it should work properly.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I was thinking in the "old" version.               This works!